# MS Bot Framework: How to get user's locale in notification-only bot?

Tags: .net, botframework, microsoft-teams

We are building a [proactive bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet) that will be rolled out to every user via Teams policy. Upon installation of the Teams App the user shall be greeted with a **localized** message and will receive occasional further **localized** messages.

The localization is the problem.

How is the bot supposed to react to changes in the user's locale in the Teams client? Assume the user switches from English to German - how is this propagated to the bot?

I tried getting the locale via `turnContext.Activity.GetLocale()` but this returns `null`. I found hints that the locale might not be set in the "install events" the bot gets when the Teams App is installed for the user. And even if it would - this wouldn't cover locale changes by the user.

Is this a supported scenario for localization? How would a solution look? Maybe an active lookup is necessary? Any hints are appreciated.

*Technical notes:*

The bot saves the initial `ConversationReference` when being installed, then uses `ContinueConversationAsync` to push messages to the user. `Locale` is always null.

The bot is marked as "notification only", so there will never be a message from user to bot.

[image]

The bot will only be used in Teams. No web chat etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known limitation currently. Bot has to wait for user to message. The message activity has clientInfo filled out in channelData with locale information.

Comment: This is unfortunate but thanks for clarifying. What is the timeline for providing notification-only bots with the capability to localize its notifications? I also created a UserVoice for this: https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/43923333-add-localization-support-for-notification-only-bot

Comment: Any updates, has this been resolved?

Comment: Please use [Install update event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/subscribe-to-conversation-events?tabs=dotnet#install-update-event) to send a welcome message and get locale.